# iPad view in universal applications

Tags: ios, tableview, universal

I am doing a universal appellation. It has a table view. If the user clicks a table cell, and the user selected iPad, it must go to another view which is designed for iPad. How can I make it possible? I am doing as follows:

```
 TwitterDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[TwitterDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TwitterDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    detailViewController.detaildict= Detaildict;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 
    {
        iPadView *iPadview = [[iPadView alloc]  initWithNibName:@"iPadView" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:iPadview animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: detailViewController should be allways pushed or only in case of iphone?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just take flag for iphone and ipad. and then

```
detailViewController.detaildict= Detaildict;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

if("check here with flag") or else  if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
iPadView *iPadview = [[iPadView alloc]  initWithNibName:@"iPadView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:iPadview animated:YES];
}
```

I hope it will work!!

Answer (score -1):

in didSelectRowAtIndexPath check condition like below

```
    TwitterDetailViewController *Twitter_obj ;
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        Twitter_obj = [[TwitterDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TwitterDetailViewController-ipad" bundle:nil];//iPad nib
    }
    else 
    {
        Twitter_obj = [[TwitterDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TwitterDetailViewController" bundle:nil];//iPhone nib
    }
    self.navigationController pushViewController:Twitter_obj animated:YES];
   [Twitter_obj release];
```